# CSS float on mobile acting up

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm having some trouble with getting my app webpage to display correctly on mobile devices. I've added some buttons for social media sharing along with a get it on Google Play button. The Google Play button was quite a bit bigger than the other two so I decided to place the social media buttons next to each other above it. It works fine in both Chrome and Firefox but when I try to access it on my phone the Facebook button appears above the other one. I've tried fiddling around with the CSS but I can't get it to work properly. The hierarchy right now looks like this:

- div "media"

  - div "sharing"

    - fb button
    - twitter button
  - Play store button

And the CSS looks like this:

```
#media 
{
    width:130px;
    float:right;
}
#fb
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
    width:48px;
}
#twitter
{
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    clear:none;
    width:56px;
}
```

The two images below shows what it looks like on the two devices.

[image: Mobile view]

[image: Web view]

Comment: @Colandus Yea, to align it to the twitter button. It puts it in the middle in regard to height. I've tried with both left and bottom as well. Nothing works..

Comment: No there's no middle. Remove the clear's and put left on fb and right on twitter

Answer (score 0):

```
#fb
{
    float:left;
    width:48px;
}
#twitter
{
    float:right;
    width:56px;
}
```

Proper float's and no clear's.

**Edit**:

In reference to your website, this is how you should solve it:

```
#fb
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

No need to float this one. You can go without the `vertical-align` as well if that suit you better.

Comment: This is rightly done, your issue must be elsewhere. Try put a background color on respective elements and see if they perhaps are colliding.

Comment: Tried setting background colors, no collision. If you go to dinreise.peterme.net you can have a look for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for float on `#media` (from what I can see in the examples). You can also get rid of `position:relative` on `#fb` and `#twitter` and replace it with `display:inline-block`.

Finally, apply `float:left` to `#fb` instead of `float:middle`.

Middle is not a valid argument for float.

Comment: Tried this before, doesn't work. And float:middle; definitely does something. At least in Chrome what happens is that it centers it vertically on the twitter div (like align on img used to do). The float:right; in media is in respect to the rest of the page.

Comment: No, there is NO such thing as middle. It will treat it as if it's not floated at all.

Comment: It isn't doing anything. I promise. See the [w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/float). If this isn't working, remove the width and ensure that #sharing is display:block, width:100%

Comment: @Colandus Aaah, float:left; aligned it to the top of the div. float:none; makes it centered, that's why I thought it did something.

Comment: @socialconquest still not working.. Page is available at dinreise.peterme.net if anyone wants to look at it themselves.

Comment: Try background:#ffffff; padding:3px 5px; on #fb and it should look good.